# Interpolated strings stored in a variable

Tags: c#, .net, string-interpolation

Is there a way to evaluate c# interpolated strings when they are already stored inside a string variable? I'm guessing they are decompolsed at compile time so this is not possible, but just curious.

Comment: I think you are looking for a scanf function, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472202/looking-for-c-sharp-equivalent-of-scanf

Comment: Dynamic compilation might be an option if you're not too concerned about performance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51255291/1149773