# How to append string to a JSON string derived from a blob using .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json, azure

I am trying to append a string to the JSON content extracted from a blob. The JSON content is similar to below.

```
    {
      "Subject": "Details",
      "FromAddress": "xyz@abc.com",
      "ToAddress": "123@890.com",
      "Body": "My name is {name} and I faced this {exception} error"
    }
```

In this, I have to append a name (e.g. Arvind) and an exception (e.g. SystemException) and send the formatted data to another method to send mail

```cs
string data = EmailBlob.DownloadTextAsync().Result;
EmailData emailData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailData>(data);
```

The variable `data` holds the following JSON

```
{
  "Subject": "Details",
  "FromAddress": "xyz@abc.com",
  "ToAddress": "123@890.com",
  "Body": "My name is {name} and I faced this {exception} error"
}
```

The variable emailData holds the below.

```
  Subject: "Details",
  FromAddress: "xyz@abc.com",
  ToAddress: "123@890.com",
  Body: "My name is {name} and I faced this {exception} error"
```

Now I have to update the name 'Arvind' and exception 'SystemException' and send the emaildata variable to another method as below.

```
  Subject: "Details",
  FromAddress: "xyz@abc.com",
  ToAddress: "123@890.com",
  Body: "My name is Arvind and I faced this SystemException error"
```

How could I achieve it using C#.NET?

Comment: why not just use Replace method like ```Body.Replace("{name}","Arvind")```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43288857/string-interpolation-with-variable-content-in-c-sharp

Comment: `string data = EmailBlob.DownloadTextAsync().Result;` should be `awaiting` this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
             EmailData.Body = EmailData.Body
                             .Replace("{name}", "Arvind")
                             .Replace("{exception}", "SystemException ");
```

Comment: Please explain code rather than just dumping code here.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply do it by String.Replace("old string","new string");
for your reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8

```
    static void ReplaceExample()
    {
        //Method 1 - you can replace the value by data itself and you can deserialize to object
        string beforeDeserialize = EmailBlob.DownloadTextAsync().Result;
        beforeDeserialize = beforeDeserialize.Replace("{name}", "Arvind").Replace("{exception}", "SystemException ");
        EmailData emailDataM1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailData>(beforeDeserialize);
        //Method 2 - you can replace the valueafter deserialize
        string afterDeserialize = EmailBlob.DownloadTextAsync().Result;
        EmailData emailDataM2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailData>(afterDeserialize);
        emailDataM2.Body = emailDataM2.Body.Replace("{name}", "Arvind").Replace("{exception}", "SystemException ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
string name = "testName", exception "testException"

emailData.Body = emailData.Body.Replace("{name}", name);
emailData.Body = emailData.Body.Replace("{exception}", exception);
```

======================================

2.

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Create variable  and replace

```
string name = "testName", exception "testException"

emailData.Body = Regex.Replace(emailData.Body, "{name}", name);
emailData.Body = Regex.Replace(emailData.Body, "{exception}", exception );
```

=> "My name is testName and I faced this testException error"

Comment: Why are you using a RegEx replacement here? There are no regular expressions here.